# Java Bubble Sorting an inversely sorted array with 3 elements.

Tags: java, algorithm

If I'm not mistaken the code for bubbleSort in Java is the following:

```
public void bubbleSort(){
   int out, in;
   for(out = nElems -1;out>1;out--){
       for(in =0; in<out; in++){
           if(a[in]>a[in+1])
               swap(in,in+1);
       }
   }
}
```

However, if you have an inversely sorted int array with 3 elements, it will not sort it correctly..

```
int[] g = {50,30,10};
```

it will come out as

```
g = {30,10,50};
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
public void bubbleSort(){
   int out, in;
   for(out = nElems -1;out>=1;out--){
       for(in =0; in<out; in++){
           if(a[in]>a[in+1])
               swap(in,in+1);
       }
   }
}
```

You went from the size of array to 2 (out > 1), but you must go to 1, so you missed the last swap.

Comment: I guess there was a typo in my textbook.. Thanks